# How to Change MS chart X axis to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, charts, binance

I have a chart that displays the latest 1000 candles(Binance API limit). I get the chart data using:

```
BinanceClient client = new BinanceClient();
        var candles = client.Spot.Market.GetKlines(symbol: "BTCUSDT", interval: (Binance.Net.Enums.KlineInterval)inter, startTime: start, endTime: end, limit: 1000).Data.ToList();
```

This is the data source.

I then build the chart using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < candles.Count; i++)
        {
            // adding date and high
            chart1.Series["Price15"].Points.AddXY(candles[i].OpenTime, candles[i].High);
            // adding low
            chart1.Series["Price15"].Points[i].YValues[1] = (double)candles[i].Low;
            //adding open
            chart1.Series["Price15"].Points[i].YValues[2] = (double)candles[i].Open;
            // adding close
            chart1.Series["Price15"].Points[i].YValues[3] = (double)candles[i].Close;
            
        }
```

This all works, but I have created 2 Functions that I believe have the same problem source.

The first function is to allow zooming into the chart area, But this does not work properly(?)
as the X axis does not display the dates correctly so it only really zooms from left to right(i.e does not zoom if the cursor is in the middle of the chart. This is done like this:

```
private void chart1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Axis xAxis = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
            double xMin = xAxis.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
            double xMax = xAxis.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
            double xPixelPos = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X);

            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {
              
                var posXStart = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) - (xMax - xMin) / 0.75;
                var posXFinish = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) + (xMax - xMin) / 1;
               

                xAxis.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
               
            }
            else if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                
                var posXStart = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) - (xMax - xMin) * 0.75;
                var posXFinish = xAxis.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) + (xMax - xMin) * 1;
                xAxis.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
                FZoomLevel++;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Second function is a Hittest to try and find my coordinate values. This worked for the Y axis, but still no values for the X axis. This is done like this:

```
 private void chart1_GetToolTipText(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.HitTestResult htr = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if (htr.ChartElementType != ChartElementType.PlottingArea && htr.ChartElementType != ChartElementType.DataPoint && htr.ChartElementType != ChartElementType.Gridlines&& htr.ChartElementType!= ChartElementType.Axis)
            return;

        ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0]; 

        double yCoord = ca.AxisY2.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);
        string s = e.X.ToString("s");
         double xCord = ca.AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
        
        


        e.Text = "\nY = " + Math.Round(yCoord, 2).ToString();
        e.Text = "\nX = " + xCord.ToString();
    }
```

My question is how can I format my X axis Like TradingView(e.g)? right now it automatically can calculate the range of dates. i.e. if I want 15min candle data from this date it will start from 2021-05-18 to 2021-05-28, but it wont display hours and x values.

background: I am trying to create an algotrading environment

Comment: For the x-axis you can only change the [axis.intervaltype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.intervaltype?view=netframework-4.8). You probably need to change the [series.xvaluetype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.xvaluetype?view=netframework-4.8) first.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but it just changes it to a hourly(which would be more accurate ). I Think i am going to try experimenting with adding another x axis

Answer (score 1):

```
chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime; 
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = (DateTimeIntervalType)DateRangeType.DayOfMonth;
       chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "mm-hh-dd";
```

You can edit the format of the x axis by first setting the `XValueType` to either `Time` or `DateTime`

Not perfect but allows for more detail when zooming in.